# How can I relocate the default quickly directory?

Tags: application-development, quickly

I don't want quickly to create applications in my home folder by default. Instead I want them to be in `~/Projects`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first get into that folder:

```
cd ~/Projects
```

and then create application:

```
quickly create ubuntu-application name-of-the-application
```

Comment: Correct, Quickly create uses your pwd for project location.